# Output a array command tester symfony2

Tags: arrays, symfony, console, command, output

How to output an array in command tester? I have a function that returns a array but when the command console generate the output becomes string thanks

Comment: Can you show the command / content of array / output ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.var-dump.php) functions.

You can also use the Symfony Helper, which also works with objects :

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($myVar);
```